# Casting to generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

We have an abstract generic class in C#, very much like this:

```
public abstract class Repository<T>
    where T: Entity
{
    public abstract void Create(T t);
    public abstract T Retrieve(Id id);
    //etc.
}
```

We have a few derived classes, such as:

```
public class EventRepository
    : Repository<Event>
{
    //etc.
}
```

We are implementing a unit of work pattern that keeps a dictionary to map entity types to repository types, so that when an entity needs to be created or changed, it knows what repository to instantiate:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Type> m_dicMapper;
```

This dictionary is initialised and loaded with all the mappings, like this:

```
m_dicMapper.Add(typeof(Event), typeof(EventRepository));
//and so on for a few other repository classes.
```

Then, when an entity `e` needs to be created, for example:

```
//retrieve the repository type for the correct entity type.
Type tyRepo = m_dicMapper[e.GetType()];
//instantiate a repository of that type.
repo = Activator.CreateInstance(tyRepo);
//and now create the entity in persistence.
repo.Create(e);
```

The problem is, what type is `repo` in the code above? I would like to declare it as of generic `Repository<T>` type, but apparently C# won't let me do it. None of the following lines compile:

```
Repository repo;
Repository<T> repo;
Repository<e.GetType()> repo;
```

I can declare it as `var`, but then I don't get access to the `Create` and other methods that `Repository<T>` implements. I was hoping to be able to use the generic class to, well, use repositories generically! But I guess I am doing something wrong.

So my question is, what workarounds of coding and/or design could I use to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: `repo = m_dicMapper[e.GetType()];` as for your declaration of `m_dicMapper`, repo is just a `Type`... Something wrong here?

Comment: You need to create an object of the type `repo`, or store an array of actual objects, not their types.

Comment: Repo's type is [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx). And it doesn't have a create method. Maybe you want your dictionary values to be of type `Repository` instead?

Comment: Most important: do you want to have a Type-Type map, and then use the type you get to instantiate a new instance, or do you want to hold a repository instance in your map?

Comment: If so, the question boils down to: how can I have (can I?) something like a `map<Type, Repository<T>>` where `typeof(T) == Type`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have fixed now the "bug" with `repo`. Thanks @LorenzoDematté and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying, I have found a solution to this. Basically, the problem was that I have a collection of things (the various repositories) that I want to treat similarly, from an abstract point of view, but they do not inherit from a common class; they are only particular reifications of a generic class, but that does not help much. Unless...

We use a repository registry class, as suggested by @Richard, having a method like this:

```
public Repository<T> GetRepository<T>(T t)  
    where T : Entity  
{  
    Type tyRepo = m_dic[t.GetType()];  
    Repository<T> repo = (Repository<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(tyRepo);  

    return repo;  
}
```

Note that the `t` argument is needed because the dictionary must be searched by `t.GetType()` rather than `typeof(T)`, in order to consider the run-time (rather than compile-time) type of the entity. If we don't do this, all entities passed are treated as being of the root type `Entity`.

Similarly, the usage of the registry needs to take this into account. When invoking the method, `dynamic` must be used to allow the run-time to determine the type of the entity as needed, rather than fixing it at compile-time. The following code fails:

```
Event ev = new Event();
Entity e = ev;
var repo = registry.GetRepository(e);
```

because e, despite being an `Event`, is resolved at compile-time as an `Entity` as far as generic resolution is concerned. You need something like this:

```
Event ev = new Event();
dynamic e = ev;
var repo = registry.GetRepository(e);
```

And this solves my problem.

Thanks to @Richard for his suggestion to create a separate repository registry, and to everyone else who have provided feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally recommend encapsulating your access to the dictionary with a separate singleton class that then wraps your dictionary getters and setters, something like a `RepositoryStore` class.

<strike>I'd recommend changing `Dictionary<Type, Type>` to `Dictionary<Type, object>`, and then handle the casting within the `RepositoryStore`; something like so?</strike>

### Update (using `Type`s and `Lazy<T>`)

If you're using .NET 4, you could take full advantage of the `Lazy` class, and change the dictionary type to be `IDictionary<Type, Lazy<object>>`. I've amended my original answer to reflect how this might work:

```
class RepositoryStore
{
    private IDictionary<Type, Lazy<object>> Repositories { get; set; }

    public RepositoryStore()
    {
        this.Repositories = new Dictionary<Type, Lazy<object>>();
    }

    public RepositoryStore Add<T, TRepo>() where TRepo : Repository<T>
    {
        this.Repositories[typeof(T)] = new Lazy<object>(() => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TRepo)));
        return this;
    }

    public Repository<T> GetRepository<T>()
    {
        if (this.Repositories.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return this.Repositories[typeof(T)].Value as Repository<T>;
        }

        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Unable to find repository for type: " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

The usage is then pretty simple...

```
var repositoryStore = new RepositoryStore()
// ... set up the repository store, in the singleton?

Repository<MyObject> myObjectRepository = repositoryStore.GetRepository<MyObject>();
myObjectRepository.Create(new MyObject());
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. There is a problem, though. I don't want to change the dictionary from <Type, Type> into <Type, object> because I want to store mappings to repository classes rather than repository instances. Using your approach would force me to instantiate all repositories from the beginning, which is not good. I'd rather keep a map to the classes, and instantiate them as needed. Any workarounds?

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly to use `Lazy<object>` rather than `object`; this should have a similar desired effect.

Comment: I have tried your approach but I couldn't make it work. It seems to rely on knowing the type of the entity `e` at compile time, which, as I said, is not the case. In other words, `GetRepository()` cannot be generic, since there is no way to specify a type when calling it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type you want at compile time, then you can use generics. For example, you could do something like:

```
m_dictMapper.Add<Event, EventRepository>();

…

var repo = m_dictMapper.Get<Event>(); // repo is statically typed as Repository<Event>
var e = repo.Create(); // e is Event
```

This requires some casting inside the implementation of dict mapper, but otherwise will work fine.

If you know the type only at runtime (e.g. you have it as a `Type` object), then your options are quite limited. I think the best option would be create a non-generic base type for `Repository`, which works with `object`s:

```
var repo = m_dictMapper.Get(typeof(Event)); // repo is statically typed as Repository
var e = repo.Create(); // e is object
```

---

Also, I find your `Create()` method very confusing. A method with that name should return the created instance, not do something to an existing instance.

Comment: @Jason I don't think so. If it were that way, it wouldn't make sense to use `e.GetType()`.

Comment: @svick: Thank you. I don't know the type at design time; I only know `e` is an entity, but its specific type will determine the specific type of repository. Hence the problem.

Comment: @CesarGon Can't you make the method that works with `e` generic? That would mean you know the type.

Comment: @svick: Problem is, I don't know the type. I only know it is derived from Entity, but it can be any one of over two dozen classes.

Comment: @svick: Also, what type is m_dictMapper in the first line?

Comment: @CesarGon A custom type you would have to write yourself.

Comment: @svick: Any indication on how to build it? That's basically my question. :-)